# How to save file from textarea in Javascript with a name?

Tags: javascript, html, download, data-uri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)

I want a client side HTML/JS solution to solve this problem - I have a user-edittable textarea A, a textfield B and a button C. When user clicks on C, she gets a file download with name equal to B.value and contents equal to A.value. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018954/) but it does not specify how to set the filename and I don't want a Flash solution like [this](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify). We can assume users are on latest Chrome browser (it's a little tool for my team)

Comment: You can set the filename by specifying a header, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http).

Comment: Doing this is in the spec but not avalible yet, see this answer to the question @JeremyJStarcher linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10667687/1615483

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because "we can assume users are on latest Chrome browser", this type of thing can be done by creating an `<a>` with attributes *download* and *href*, and then clicking on it.
Example code below.

```
var Download = {
    click : function(node) {
        var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        return node.dispatchEvent(ev);
    },
    encode : function(data) {
            return 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + btoa( data );
    },
    link : function(data, name){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = name || self.location.pathname.slice(self.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        a.href = data || self.location.href;
        return a;
    }
};
Download.save = function(data, name){
    this.click(
        this.link(
            this.encode( data ),
            name
        )
    );
};

Download.save('hello world', 'my_file.txt');
```