# saving an image in a windows 8 application using javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I'm writing an application for windows 8 that displays images from a json file.
i would like to add the ability to save the images to my local machine but i dont know where to start.

so im just asking for advice and where to look to find out how to do this, id like to make it clear that im not asking people for code but just for some guidance on how i could find out how to go about this.

thank you in advance

EDIT:
i found a way of doing it in after a bit more looking around, I found i was able to do a ajax call on the image i was trying to save and have it return a Blob this was then written to a file

Comment: A [**previous answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12718755/1615483) of mine may be helpful. If you want a full save-as dialog but can't assume there is a default behaviour set up (i.e. direct to a certain folder), you have to allow right click -> save as OR use a non-JavaScript method (i.e. pass image to Flash or Java)

Comment: thank you for the advice however the application i am developing doesnt have right click capability and isnt able to utilize other languages, i am working on a windows 8 desktop application that is built using purely html5 and javascript. I found a way in the end i shall be posting the answer below, thank you again though.

Comment: If you think this has value for others please add the solution as answer then accept it to mark the question as solved; otherwise please delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way of doing it in after a bit more looking around, I found i was able to do a ajax call on the image i was trying to save and have it return a Blob this was then written to a file