# Where does <input type="file"> store the path of the last file uploaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to access this property and hopefully change it, so that my event listener, that listens to the event `change`, gets invoked on two consecutive uploads of the same file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655391/storing-the-image-from-an-html-input-file-form-locally

Comment: So, it is not possible to change this path. I still have to react when the same file is uploaded two times after each other, because it might happen that the file has changed, and I need to get this information. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I have an event listener registered to `change`. It gets invoked when I upload a file, say `import_file.csv`. If, after some time, I decide to upload the same file, the event listener is not invoked. Because there is no change, I guess. However, the file itself **has changed** and I want my listener to get these changes.

Comment: What if the user has two different files with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
var $c  = $("#container");
var $f1 = $("#container .f1");

function FChange() {
    alert("f1 changed");
    
    $(this).remove();
    $("<input type='file' class='f1' />").change(FChange).appendTo($c);
}

$f1.change(FChange);
```

```css
.f1 { z-index: 2 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <input type="file" class="f1">
</div>
```