# Is it possible to have a button start a download of a dom element?

Tags: javascript, svg, dojo, d3.js

I have an svg that is generated in a page, I am not bringing it in from an outside source. I want this svg to be downloadable for printing. Is there a way (using client side Javascript) to download a dom node as a text file? I am limited to dojo and d3 libraries for this project.

Comment: Since I haven't had the time to complete my answer, here are links for further information: [File API: Writer, FileSaver Interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#the-filesaver-interface), [Sample code of an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160720/create-a-file-using-javascript-in-chrome-on-client-side/7160827#7160827). Note that the neccessary feature aren't implemented in all browsers (e.g. no IE 10) support because they're still a draft. See also here: [Can I use: Fileystem](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the client is using a HTML5 web browser, this can be achieved pretty easily using [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a)s [*download* attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download). You will need to [simulate a click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.initMouseEvent) with a [*MouseEvent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent) on this element if you want the behaviour to be invoked by some other means, but the node does not have to be appended to the document. [I've answered a **similar question** about this before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12718755/1615483), but here, set the `<a>`s *href* to the svg's file location unless it is created dynamically ‒ in that case you would encode the text describing it to create a [*data URI*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs).

XML text describing a SVG can be obtained from it's [*SVGSVGElement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/SVGSVGElement) node using [*XMLSerializer*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer).

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
serializer.serializeToString(svg); // xml string for `svg` (your node)
```

Please note that any "Save As" dialogue will depend on the client's configuration.

```
// assuming var `svg` for your SVG node
var a = document.createElement('a'), xml, ev;
a.download = 'my_svg.svg'; // file name
xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg); // convert node to xml string
a.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + btoa(xml); // create data uri
// <a> constructed, simulate mouse click on it
ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Comment: The SVG I am trying to make downloadable is not in a file, it is generated in the browser using d3.js. I have no outside file to reference, just a domNode.

Comment: So you want to know how to get the string describing it from the SVGSVGElement? Edited in how to do that too, now.

Comment: @AdamSpurgin also, the data URI doesn't really need to be in base64 as the XML is a string, but safety first! Changing the MIME should be okay, too. I chose _application/octet-stream_ because it should start a download even if the browser doesn't understand a _download_ attribute (although you usually end up with a hash as a file name).

Comment: Is there any way to specify a filename otherwise? From firefox all i get is a hash name, not really an option for me.

Comment: The [MDN page about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) suggests that it might be some same-origin stuff making it break in FireFox? Maybe file a bug on bugzilla.